# How to get Windows Explorer type look and feel inside my Application?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I just got a project in which i need to create a `windows explorer` type application. I need to include various folders , Folders/Documents inside folders. And whatever folder/Document you select from left side, result will be shown in the right side panel.

As i am new to this all i don't know what to do and how to do. I have searched many sites but din't get any proper solution. So finally i am asking my question here. Please can you suggest how do i perform this using `ASP.net with C#`.

P.S. The application which is currently shown in image is a windows based application. And is developed in `DevExpress`.

[image]

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions here. You should provide a detailed description of the problem. This question is to broad.

Comment: @pratikpatel -  Please provide more description here... else no one's gonna a help you here.. What exactly you want?

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive answer to this, and I don't pretend to give one.

Keep in mind that making a clone of Windows Explorer is a daunting task. Instead the objective should be to create an application that anybody familiar with Windows Explorer can pick and use. Although, you need to start at the desired output, and see what is it you really need from this application - because not every feature will be viable.

Are you trying to make a virtual file manager? that looks like Windows Explorer? Then look for [izwebfilemanager](http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/) and look no futher. They have dedicate a good amount of time on that task.

Note: their online demo is long down - but get an screenshot:

[image]

---

If that is not what you are looking for, instead you want that appearance but provide a completely different functionality then, I think the real problem lies in the UI... you got to build it HTML + CSS + JavaScript.

Let's look at is that tree/list view at that left... I did look for some implementations...

- This one in particular looks promising: [BlueShoes TreeView](http://www.blueshoes.org/en/javascript/tree/)
- for something closer to our dear .NET you can try [DevExpress Tree List](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Tree_List/) (yet I think it is paid)
- and also check [10 Javascript & CSS TreeView and Sitemap Plugins and Tutorials](http://www.queness.com/post/1138/10-javascriptcss-treeview-and-sitemap-plugins-and-tutorials) for a other alternatives.

I have been unable to find an already made solution for the icons area of the right, yet I am sure it can be done.

---

You will have to break down "Windows Explorer look and feel" to more specific requirements, I suggest to make a minimal version as an experiment to see what user actually would be doing with your app. Do you need multiple selection? Do you need drag and drop? etc...